ReferenceError: SHA-1 / ReactNative
I created a new React Native project in which I want to integrate Native Wind. I saw that it was recommended to use Metro for several reasons. On the Native Wind documentation, I read and followed each step. But when I launch expo start in my terminal, this error appears:
iOS Bundling failed 304ms index.js (540 modules)
ERROR  ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/polyfills/require.js is not computed.
Potential causes:

You have symlinks in your project - watchman does not follow symlinks.
Check blockList in your metro.config.js and make sure it isn't excluding the file path.
at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:181:13)
at Transformer._getSha1 (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:15:26)
at Transformer.transformFile (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:92:19)
at Bundler.transformFile (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:43:30)
at Object.transform (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:134:12)
at transform (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:164:26)
at visit (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:82:29)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at buildSubgraph (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/buildSubgraph.js:103:3)
at Graph._buildDelta (/opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/expo/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Graph.js:157:22)

Here my metro.config.js :
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");
const { withNativeWind } = require('nativewind/metro');

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname, { isCSSEnabled: true })

module.exports = withNativeWind(config, { input: './global.css' })`

And here my package.json :
{
  "name": "ariane",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~52.0.18",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "nativewind": "^4.1.23",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.76.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.16.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.12.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.26.3",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.76.5"
  },
  "private": true
}

I just created a project with the command npx create-expo-app@latest --template blank and then integrated Babel and Metro.
Nothing else, the app was working fine before Metro was in my project.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
